# Sliding the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with some stuff in it. At the start its width is set to 0; (So it appears invisible), but I would like to have a link and then have a javascript/jQuery to make that div "slide" to abut 100px in width. How can I do that?

I don't "get" the accordion examples i've seen cos it's too involved for what I want to do.

Can someone please help me? Any help is appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Have looked into jQuery UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? : http://jsfiddle.net/k45zb/

Uses jQuery's `animate()` method to increase the width. You can change the duration to your liking of course.

```
#thediv {
    width: 0px;
    background:red;
}

<div id='thediv'>
    some content
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#thediv').animate({'width': '100px'}, 3000);
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/animate

Comment: Perfect. Just what I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For vertical slide (use slideToggle function to toggle the divs)

```
<script>

$(function(){

    $('.hidden').hide();

    $('#toggle').click(

        function (){
            $('.hidden').slideToggle();
        }
    )

});

</script>

<div class="hidden">This is you div</div>
<a href="#" id="toggle">toggle</a>
```